# RabbitMQ - How to find out the Queue mode (default or lazy)

Tags: rabbitmq

The question is simple, In RabbitMQ, How to find out the Queue mode (default or lazy).

I have tried documentation and experimenting with:

1. Rabbitmqctl
2. Rabbitmq management plugin
3. HTTP API
4. AMQPLib for nodeJs

I know how to set that using policies, I simply want to know the current mode of a queue *when the mode is set upon declaration and **not** via a policy*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the HTTP API to do that:
for example, the list of the queues with all the attributes:

```
curl  -u guest:guest 'localhost:15672/api/queues'
```

you have to find:

```
"mode": "lazy"
```

or

```
"arguments": {
            "x-queue-mode": "lazy"
        },
```

Simply in this way:

```
curl  -u guest:guest \
    'localhost:15672/api/queues' | python -m json.tool | grep '"mode": "lazy"' -A 50 -B 10
```

or

```
curl  -u guest:guest \
    'localhost:15672/api/queues' | python -m json.tool | grep '"x-queue-mode"' -A 80 -B 3
```

or with some language to do that.

Comment: its called just `mode` now apparently in rabbitmq 3.7.8 as it returns from the api you mentioned. This helped, thanks!

Comment: you are right! thanks for pointing out!, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using managament plugin I created new queue with lazy mode:
[image: creating new queue]

Then I can see that the mode is set up:

[image: show queue properties]

Is it wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but as I mentioned in my question, I can see when I apply it via policy but not when I do it while creating the queue. I wanted to see if my code was working correctly or not, so even if I could see that it was running in `default` mode and not `lazy` as I intended it would solve the issue. Thanks for taking the time out to help though.

Comment: Did you get other data using Rabbitmq management plugin then using http api? In both cases I see "x-queue-mode" attribute. You said that you are interested in any of the 4 ways :).

Comment: No, I said I tried them but couldn't find anything, this is the sentence which I was telling you about: "I know how to set that using policies, I simply want to know the current mode of a queue when the mode is set upon declaration and not via a policy."

Comment: Creating queue by Rabbitmq management plugin means creating via a policy?

Comment: you are right, I misread your answer, but in my case creating the queue from the console wasnt an option. But yes, I had misread your answer originally.